# @Transaction readOnly on Spring repo and save on another repo

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, stream

I have implemented following code part:

```
        public void computeAllBilling() {
    orderRepository.getAll().parallel().forEach(ordreEntity -> {
        Billing billing = computedBilling(orderEntity);
        billingRepository.save(billing);
        entityManager.detach(ordreEntity);
    });
}

public interface BillingRepository extends JpaRepository<BillingEntity, String> {

    @QueryHints(value = {
            @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "1"),
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_READONLY, value = "true")
    })
    @Query(value = "SELECT o.* FROM raw.ordre o", nativeQuery = true)
    Stream<BillingEntity> getAll();
}
```

I need to stream my reading very quickly from one table, but in our business processing, we need to save the billing at the ending (after reader one order its billing must be saved)

But following this link: https://www.geekyhacker.com/2019/03/26/high-performance-data-fetching-using-spring-data-jpa-stream/

I need finally to save in another repository, not the reader repository.
Anyone know a mean to avoid

"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.
"

please ? Great thank, and best regards

Adrian